# Computer keeps stuttering every few seconds

Tags: freeze, virus, error-logging

Recently my computer has started freezing while making weird sounds while playing videos. This happens on all kind of videos; from youtube to live streams. It happens around once every five seconds. The video is not buffering, it just freezes for a split second and during that split second the audio makes a robotic sound, I'm guessing because a tiny piece of audio is repeated very often, kind of like what happens sometimes when there's a scratch on your DVD and the video stops while the audio is "stuck" too.

What could be the source of this? I don't seem to be having any other problems. However, now that I'm typing this I notice that my screen freezes for a very short time every couple of seconds, like there is lag for a split second. I'm guessing these issues are related.

edit: I looked at my eventviewer, these are some of the warnings/errors:

- DSN client event 1014 - Name resolution for the name www.overclock.net timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded (a lot of these! Also the most recent)
- A problem prevented Customer Experience Improvement Program data from being sent to Microsoft, (Error 80070005).

Comment: Maybe I should change the title? I've noticed that this is not just an issue that affects videos, my entire computer is affected, it just happens to be much more noticeable when there is audio.

Comment: Gotta ask.. Reboot yet?

Comment: @Spencer5051 This is the second or third time this has happened within the span of the week or so, so..yes. Didn't work sadly. I'd also like to add that my computer is less than a year old, so I think (hope) it isn't my hardware dying on me.

Comment: Open your task manager and watch the performance tab.. make sure your cpu isn't maxing out and your ram is not all used up.  check no processes are running out of control.  Run a memory test.  Actually, is your PC overheating?.. its probably that or Ram issue IMO.

Comment: @Spencer5051 My CPU utilization is usually under 5% when I don't actively use the internet, with occasional peaks of up to 20%. When I watch a simple video on youtube, the CPU utilization is between 10-15% but it jumps to 35-60% (most of the time closer to 35 than to 60) everytime it stutters. What does this indicate? The diagram looks like a mountain range, not even close to a straight line.

Comment: Well, that sounds like its being pretty normal.  Since it doesnt sound like a simple issue to diagnose.. there are a few things for you to consider.  You should probably run a virus / malware scan.  You could try testing your ram.  Lastly you can backup all your data and do a fresh OS install of windows.  Just thought.. you should probably run updates / check video drivers too.

Answer (score 1):

As windows uses the hard drive for swap files, temp files, and more it could be hard drive related.

Try from an administrative command prompt

chkdsk /r c:

Yes, do this when the computer reboots.

When you have several hours of downtime reboot and let it run.

Then see if it gets any better.

I used to suggest mhdd, but that is virtually impossible to get working and detecting your hard drive as its a DOS program.

Now, Victoria at http://hdd.by  You will need to use google translate as the website is in Russian.  However, the software has an english interface.

Goto the "Test" tab select **verify** and **remap** and then **scan**.  While that is running go back to the 1st or 2nd tab and click "Get SMART".

Record these numbers so you can make a comparison of before and after.

Remapped sectors, pending sectors, ECC errors, or CRC errors if these number increase significantly your hard drive could be wearing out.

When the test is done take a look at the number of sectors at or above 1s or 1000ms.  These correspond to red,green, and orange blocks.  The majority of your hard drive should be in the 25 or 100ms categories.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try... disabling the Customer Experience Improvement Program?

Here's a link to Microsoft's own documentation on disabling it.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766341%28v=ws.10%29.aspx